# How to run docker-compose up on deploy

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose` file, and I want to send it to Heroku, to then execute`docker-compose up -d --build`.

I found more than a hundred examples of how to do something like `heroku container:push web`, but this is not what I need.

Now I have only 5 services in `docker-compose`, but what do I do, when they will be 30?

Answer (score 5):

docker-compose is not supported but Heroku provides heroku.yml to deal with multiple images:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Comment: And I need to completely rewrite my `docker-compose` file?